# Filtrar resultados en PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una página de mensajes en PHP y MySQL, tengo una tabla llamada `usuarios` con los campos `id`, `user`, `edad`, `pais` y `ciudad`.

Me gustaría que el usuario pudiese buscar otros usuarios según ciertos parámetros, como por ejemplo la edad; para ello tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
        <label>Search By: </label> <br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="usernam" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="number" value="" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="10" max="150"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="country" placeholder="country"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="city" placeholder="city"> <br><br>
    <input id="" type="submit" value="Search" name="search"></form>
```

Y luego el siguiente código PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
   $usernam = $_POST['usernam'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $country = $_POST['country'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];
 }
```

Me falta hacer la consulta SQL para obtener los datos, pero no sé cómo podría conseguir que si el usuario no introduce todos parámetros (por ejemplo introduce solo los campos país y ciudad) que la consulta ignore los campos que están en blanco, que en este ejemplo serían `usuario` y `edad`.

¿Cómo podría realizar esta consulta?

Comment: ¿Usas PDO o mysqli?

Comment: @OscarGarcia te refieres por su vulnerabilidad de datos? o para responder?

Comment: Es para responder, no quiero programar en un tipo y luego rehacer el código de nuevo para que lo puedas usar.

Comment: La mejor solución a mi parecer sería declarar una consulta base y comenzar a concatenar dependiendo si los campos `input` fueron llenados o no.

Comment: Estoy utilizando PDO @OscarGarcia

Comment: Ok, voy a redactar mi respuesta, una última pregunta: ¿usas MyISAM o InnoDB como almacenamiento de la base de datos?

Comment: Pues la estoy probando en localhost, utilizo MariaDB @OscarGarcia

Comment: MariaDB soporta XtraDB (como Percona), InnoDB, Aria y MyISAM. Si me confirmas que usas una que soporte `fulltext` sin restricciones te sugeriré una mejora que "lo vas a flipar" (perdón por la expresión :)

Comment: Pues a pesar de quedar como una novata, no estoy segura jaja @OscarGarcia

Comment: ¿Podrías ejecutar un `SHOW CREATE TABLE usuarios` (ver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) para que me confirmes el `Engine` usado?

Comment: No sé si es esto @OscarGarcia: CREATE TABLE usuarios (
                id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                edad INT(2) NOT NULL,
                ciudad VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                pais VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                );";

Comment: @kalia te faltan mas datos o eso es todo lo que te devolvio la consulta?

Comment: Acabo de verlo ahora, se me había pasado esa línea jaja es InnoDB @OscarGarcia

Comment: Ya te he redactado la respuesta con tres ejemplos diferentes, una búsqueda fulltext, una búsqueda de texto contenido dentro de un campo y otra búsqueda comparando un valor entero. Espero que te sea de ayuda :) Todo está ejecutado como consulta preparada y es inmune a ataques de inyección SQL (el resto de ejemplos que te han puesto son vulnerables).

Comment: ¡Tengo una errata! Cambia `push_array` por `array_push`. Estoy editando mi respuesta. Siento la molestia :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usando PDO podrías implementar tu búsqueda de la siguiente manera:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  /* Consulta raíz */
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
  /* Aquí almacenaremos los WHERE que se unirán con un "AND" */
  $where = [];
  /* Por ahora no tenemos ningún campo de búsqueda para PDO */
  $campos = [];
  /* Si queremos una búsqueda de usuario preparamos todo para hacerla */
  if (!empty($_POST['usernam'])) {
    /* Agregamos al WHERE la comparación */
    array_push($where, 'INSTR(LOWER(:usernam), LOWER(user)) > 0');
    /* Preparamos los datos para la variable preparada */
    $campos[':usernam'] = [
      'valor' => $_POST['usernam'],
      'tipo' => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
    ];
  }
  /* Hacemos lo mismo con el resto de campos del formulario */
  if (!empty($_POST['age'])) {
    array_push($where, 'edad = :age');
    $campos[':age'] = [
      'valor' => $_POST['age'],
      'tipo' => \PDO::PARAM_INT,
    ];
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['country'])) {
    array_push($where, 'MATCH (pais) AGAINST (:country IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)');
    $campos[':country'] = [
      'valor' => $_POST['country'],
      'tipo' => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
    ];
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['city'])) {
    array_push($where, 'MATCH (ciudad) AGAINST (:city IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)');
    $campos[':city'] = [
      'valor' => $_POST['city'],
      'tipo' => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
    ];
  }
  /* Si tenemos cláusulas WHERE las unimos */
  if (!empty($where)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
  }
  $consulta = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  /* Si no hay elementos en $campos no se ejecutará este bucle */
  foreach($campos as $clave => $valores) {
    $consulta->bindParam($clave, $valores['valor'], $valores['tipo']);
  }
  $resultado = $consulta->execute();
}
```

En el código hay comentarios que explican el funcionamiento paso a paso.

He usado búsquedas `fulltext` en algunos campos (por ponerte un ejemplo de uso), una comparación numérica y también la función [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) junto con [`LOWER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) para que la comparación no sea sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Para hacer uso de búsquedas `fulltext` optimizadas hay que modificar el esquema de la tabla ejecutando:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD FULLTEXT (pais, ciudad)
```

Las búsquedas `fulltext` tienen muchas ventajas, como que considera "látigo" y "latigo" como palabras iguales (translitera al comparar, o mejor dicho, normaliza al indexar) y es insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Comment: +1 por escribir una respuesta basada en código seguro, contra la Inyección SQL.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Iba a usar un `user LIKE CONCAT('%', :usernam, '%')`, pero al final me decanté por un `INSTR/LOWER` para dar variedad en la respuesta :)

Answer (score 2):

Para estos casos tendrias que utlizar el **operador** `SQL LIKE`:

El operador `LIKE` se utiliza en una cláusula `WHERE` para buscar un patrón especificado en una columna.

Hay dos comodines utilizados junto con el operador `LIKE`:

```
% - El signo de porcentaje representa cero, uno o varios caracteres
_ - El subrayado representa un solo carácter
```

> Entonces tu consulta seria algo asi:

```
"Select * from usuarios where user like '%'$usernam'%' and edad like '%'$age'%' and pais like '%'$country'%'and ciudad like '%'$city'%'"
```

> Esto te devolvera resultados con los parametros que hayan puesto, no importa si solo an puesto un solo parametro o todos

Comment: Y dale con escribir código **vulnerable**. Has escrito ese tipo de consultas que le encantan a los hackers. -1 porque PDO existe, entre otras cosas, para que no escribas **jamás** consultas como estas.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción seria validar si las variables tienen un valor y de acuerdo a estos resultados ir armando la consulta:
Aquí un ejemplo de como podría ser:

```
<?php 
   //evitamos que el usuario envie espacios en blanco
    $usernam = trim($_POST['usernam']);
    $age = trim($_POST['age']);
    $country = trim($_POST['country']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    if ($usernam =="" AND $age =="" AND $country =="" AND $city =="" AND) {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM nombreTabla";
        ......//demas codigo
    }else{
        $sql='SELECT * FROM nombreTabla WHERE';
        if ($usernam != "") {
            $sql=' user = "$usernam" AND';
        }if ($age != "") {
            $sql=' edad = $age AND';
        }if ($country != "") {
            $sql=' pais = "$country" AND';
        }if ($city != "") {
            $sql=' ciudad = "$city" AND';
        }
        $sqlFinal=trim($sql, 'AND');//quitamos el ultim AND para evitar error
        .....//demas codigo
    }
 ?>
```

lo puedes adaptar a tu conveniencia.

> Esta forma es muy practica pero puedes correr el riesgo de Sql Inyection

Comment: puedo mejorar un poco tu pregunta?

Comment: @JackNavaRow si no tengo ningun problema

Comment: Porque quitarle tiempo al servidor con este tipo de if? si lo puedes hacer en la BD con una sola sentencia

Comment: Recuerden que son inpust y no siempre lo van a poner a corde a la BD es decir si se llama luis lo puede poner lui y le sale luis usando LIKE encambio le sale error si lo compara defrente

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores, El op no menciona  esa posibilidad, ademas solo es un aporte cada quien puede ver si le es apto o no en su proyecto

Comment: Otro escritor de **código vulnerable**. No entiendo por qué escriben ustedes ese tipo de consultas que tanto les encantan a los hackers. Al igual que en la respuesta de Ivan, te daré -1 por esto. PDO existe, entre otras cosas, para que no escribas **jamás** consultas como estas.